# Is there a way to secure an IOT device (e.g. ESP32) that is physically accessible?

Tags: iot, esp32

How do you secure IOT devices (e.g. ESP32) out in the field that is physically accessible, given that their SSL client certificate can be copied and used for impersonation and/or publishing wrong data to the server/broker? Alternatively, is there a way of knowing if the IoT client has been compromised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to secure the hardware is by adding an embedded security module, and if not possible an external one.

The range of solutions range from embedded modules such as

-Integrated Circuit modules like the https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATECC508A 
which might be compatible with the module you specified

-to more general purpose hardware secured USB stick, like here: https://www.techradar.com/news/best-secure-drives

-to a secured local storage module on the IOT device

-to a dedicated Hardware Security Module (HSM)

All pending on your specific application and needs.

Comment: Referring to the ATECC Integrated Circuit (IC), the solution should work as long as no one desolders this crypto-authentication IC from the IoT device and uses it for impersonation, right? Perhaps the use of ATECC IC and epoxy potting will make it harder for the IoT device to be compromised?

Comment: High quality secured IC should not allow retrieval of secret information, even if disassembled from the main circuit. Some of them stop functioning when a disassembly attempt is made - hardware self destruction. 
Given that a two way authentication between client and server is used, no one else will be able to authenticate as the IoT device, as its private key will not be retrievable.
Adding epoxy potting will no doubt strengthen the security of the solution, but is not mandatory if the IC secured element is indeed disassembly resistant.